# Why aren't users sometimes allowed to suggest edits to (or edit) questions?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I got the error message `Users cannot suggest edits` when trying to suggest an edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496976/creating-array-with-unknown-elements-by-input-them).

Why do I get this message?
And, more importantly: How can I make sure I can suggest edits again?

Comment: You can suggest edits by clicking the "edit" link which is below every post.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Users are not allowed.Even if I have commented once,I am not allowed to suggest an edit.

Comment: @MathewsMathai Um...no?  You can suggest an edit to [almost] any post, unless you've been edit banned for some reason.

Comment: The only time a low rep user (one without the "edit questions and answers" privilege)  cannot suggest an edit is if there is **already** a suggested edit pending approval.

Comment: I recently got a message saying `Users cannot suggest edits`.What does that mean?

Comment: You currently have a suggested edit from me. Would that convince you?

Comment: The only thing I did was comment

Comment: Can you link at which question you got that message?

Comment: @MathewsMathai - where did you get this message? When? Was there a pending suggested edit?

Comment: @Simon Klaver I didn't recieve a suggestion yet.I am only talking about users(which I guess is the person who has already commented or added an answer).

Comment: @MathewsMathai Whether you've commented or answered has nothing to do with your ability to suggest an edit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496976/creating-array-with-unknown-elements-by-input-them#comment56735672_34496976

Comment: @MathewsMathai - almost every user of these sites can suggest an edit. Every single one. Even those who are not registered. Even those who have never contributed a single question/answer/comment/vote. There is a small number of sites that do require registration first (Stack Overflow is the largest such site, but not the only one). Open an anonymous tab - go to most SE sites to a question - there is an "improve this question/answer" link on it.

Comment: The post you linked to had a [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10706742) on it - you may have attempted to suggest an edit while that one was pending. It took 15 minutes to be approved - in that time no edits were allowed on it.

Comment: Well,Are you people actually thinking that I am lying???

Comment: We are saying the post is clearly incorrect. People **can** and **do** suggest edits - you have done so yourself. What we are asking for is clarification, as what you posted is not a representation of the experience people here have.

Comment: @Oded Can you throw some light on this message `User can not suggest edits`?

Comment: It accepted my edit for that particular question this time but I got that particular error thrice.

Comment: @MathewsMathai - I thought [I already did](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272028/why-arent-users-allowed-to-suggest-edits-to-or-edit-questions#comment882745_272028). Are you sure that's the **exact** phrase? If I can't get a grep result for that, it isn't in the codebase.

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work for me.I don't see any possible reason for me to be banned from suggesting edits.That is the exact phrase as much as I remember. @Oded

Comment: Did you even read what I wrote? There was a pending suggested edit that took 15 minutes to be approved. Within those 15 minutes no one was able to edit the question. How is that the same as a ban? As far as I can see you are not been banned from suggested edits.

Comment: Okay.So the message was the thing which confused me. sorry @Oded

Comment: The.Lack of.Space after.Periods makes it.Really hard to read.What you write.

Comment: @MathewsMathai I see what your issue was. I think this was very poorly handled by the community here, and that this question could be very good. However, how it is currently worded I think it is very unclear, and should have probably been closed until revised.

Comment: I agree with @HATMAN. This is poor result of total misunderstanding how things work, and not really checking things before jumping to conclusions

Comment: @Shadow Wizard The way I put it into words was a bit confusing. The message I got while suggesting an edit was confusing too.

Comment: @MathewsMathai no, that's not the message we get. Either your memory betrays you, or you bumped into a very weird bug. In those cases, the edit link is there, but disabled, with such tooltip: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fxQtf.png. If you somehow get to the edit page directly, this is what you see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hqLVp.png. There was never message like "Users cannot suggest edits". Next time, please take screenshots and be **much** more specific and clear.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard I'll take a screenshot and post it next time!

Comment: If you're quick enough you might be able to reproduce it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34507520/qsort-float-2d-array-bug-in-this-value-stdlib-h) (try to edit)

Answer (score 7):

Considering that [you've suggested 10 edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5482966/mathews-mathai?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) clearly you *know* that edits can be suggested to posts.

Why you're proposing a feature that not only already exists, but that *you've used repeatedly* is beyond me.

Note that edits cannot be suggested to locked posts, posts with another pending suggested edit, or by users that have been temporarily banned from suggesting edits.

Comment: I didn't say I can't suggest edits.

Comment: @Math Then you're just being unclear.

Comment: @MathewsMathai Your question is, "Why aren't users allowed to suggest edits", which seems to imply pretty strongly that you can't suggest edits.  If you can, the question makes no sense.

Comment: I mentioned that I got a message which said `Users can't suggest edits` which basically counts me as a user because I had commented on that post before suggesting an edit.

Comment: Why would I post a question without any reason?....Of course I am aware that a person can suggest edits...but what about thaf error message?

Comment: @MathewsMathai Yet you didn't post that in your question, didn't link to the post, and included literally no other related information.  You just asked why users can't suggest edits, and they can.  I'll also note that *you got your answer anyway* as I included in my answer the situations in which an edit cannot be suggested.

Comment: @MathewsMathai "Why would I post a question without any reason?"  I have no idea why.  Thousands of people ask extremely low quality, often quite senseless, questions every day.  I've long sicne stopped trying to figure out why.